# How to batch rearrange the interface by the amount of numbers/letters?

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch file (Microsoft .bat) and would like to know how do I rearrange the interface echo on automatically when the move from X caracters?

How is:

```
┌────────────┐
│Ping: 50ms  |
└────────────┘

┌────────────┐
│Ping: 1ms  |
└────────────┘

┌────────────┐
│Ping: 200ms  |
└────────────┘
```

how I wish:

```
┌────────────┐
│Ping: 50ms  |
└────────────┘    
┌────────────┐
│Ping: 1ms   |
└────────────┘
┌────────────┐
│Ping: 200ms |
└────────────┘
```

Note 1: The number/letter is random ranging from one digit and 3 digits.

Note 2: The characters are just around to represent how it will look in the end in view that I use here the Terminal font characters they have not passed that desire.

My Code:

```
@Echo Off
Title Ping
Color 1f
mode con:lines=12 cols=39
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Set "IPServidor=104.16.22.33"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "lowPing=9999"
set "highPing=0"


Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ


:doPing

set "ping="

for /f "tokens=9" %%a in ('
ping -n 2 "%IPServidor%" ^|find "ms,"
') do for /f "delims=m " %%b in ("%%a") do set "ping=%%~b"

Cls

if not defined ping  (
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo  ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
echo  ³ ¯ O servidor nÆo est  respodendo! ³
Echo  ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
goto :doPing
)

Cls

if %ping% gtr %highPing% set "highPing=%ping%"
if %ping% lss %lowPing%  set "lowPing=%ping%"

Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping atual:  %ping%ms   ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping m¡nimo: %lowPing%ms   ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping m ximo: %highPing%ms   ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ

Goto :doPing
```

Comment: Are you talking about Microsoft .bat files?

Comment: Yes, and if possible would be very happy if you help me up.

Comment: Show us the code that is generating your string (`Ping: 200ms`), then we can help you.

Comment: @aphoria, what does that have to do with the formatting?!

Comment: I added my code, it varies from 1ms to 999ms. and when you get home from 1 or 3 digits formatting breaks.

Comment: @aioobe In other languages, the display formatting would be independent of how the value is generated. In a batch file, the formatting and value are intertwined. We need to see the batch code to show how to format the value the desired way.

Comment: In my comment above, I should have said "In a batch file, the formatting and value _may be_ interwined."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right-align your ping number and have it used a fixed number of spaces.

Try this right before you display your `%ping%` variable.

```
SET ping=  %ping%
SET ping=%ping:~-3%
```

Basically, the first line adds two spaces in front of the number and then the second line takes the 3 right-most characters.

So, if the value of `%ping%` is `1`, you would get this:

```
┌────────────┐
│Ping:   1ms |
└────────────┘
```

If the value of `%ping%` is `99`, you would get this:

```
┌────────────┐
│Ping:  99ms |
└────────────┘
```

And, if the value of `%ping%` is `999`, you would get this:

```
┌────────────┐
│Ping: 999ms |
└────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, you guys are incredible!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from the people here, I managed to complete my code and for this I am posting it below:

```
@Echo Off
Title Ping
Color 1f
mode con:lines=12 cols=39
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Set "IPServidor=104.16.22.33"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "lowPing=9999"
set "highPing=  0"


Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ


:doPing

set "ping="

for /f "tokens=9" %%a in ('
ping -n 2 "%IPServidor%" ^|find "ms,"
') do for /f "delims=m " %%b in ("%%a") do set "ping=%%~b"

Cls

if not defined ping  (
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo  ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
echo  ³ ¯ O servidor nÆo est  respodendo! ³
Echo  ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
goto :doPing
)

Cls

SET ping=   %ping%
SET ping=%ping:~-3%
if %ping% gtr %highPing% set "highPing=%ping%"
if %ping% lss %lowPing%  set "lowPing=%ping%"

Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping atual:  %ping%ms  ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping m¡nimo: %lowPing%ms  ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping m ximo: %highPing%ms  ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ

Goto :doPing
```